# Javascript property exist and scope

Tags: javascript, extjs

I try to create a few objects like this:

```
Object_level_1 = Ext.extend ( Ext.util.Observable, {
  PropA: null,
  ProbB: null,
  initComponent: function () {
    Object_level_1.superclass.initComponent.call ();
  },
  setValue: function ( name, value ) { // it will come as 'PropA', 45 
    if ( this.hasOwnProperty ( name ) ) { // ' fixed base on dtan answer
       // here is a problem 1
       // how I can access correct property and set it up
       // problem 2
       // How I set up property value of right property by having variable name
       this.fireEvent ( 'Update_on_level_1' );
    }    
  }
}

Object_level_2 = Ext.extend ( Object_level_1, {
  PropC: null,
  ProbD: null,
  initComponent: function () {
    Object_level_1.superclass.initComponent.call ();
  },
  setValue: function ( name, value ) { // it will come as 'PropA', 45 or 'PropC', 100
    Object_level_2.superclass.setValue ( name, value );
    if ( this.hasOwnProperty ( name ) ) { // ' fixed base on dtan answer
       // here is a problem 1 again
       // how I can access correct property and set it up
       // problem 2 again
       // How I set up property value of right property by having variable name
       this.fireEvent ( 'Update_on_level_2' );
    }    
  }
}
```

Does someone know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this to your `if` statement:

```
if ( name in this && this.hasOwnProperty(name) && this[name]) {
   this.fireEvent ( 'Update_on_level_2' );
}
```

<strike>the `this[name]` i believe is more for IE b/c I have read that it has some problems with `hasOwnProperty` on its own (this might be a legacy thing though for IE6 and not be much of a problem for the newer versions).</strike>  the the `this[name]` is there to make sure your property has a value.  If you don't care that the value is `false` or `null`, then that portion can be taken out. Also, the `hasOwnProperty` method excludes properties from the `prototype`, which sounds like what you are going for.

edit.
as per @Pointy's comment below.

Comment: The check for `this[name]` is not for IE weaknesses. It's possible for an object to have a property, but the value of the property might be null.  However, the check `this[name]` will be `false` also if the property is not null but equal to numeric zero, the boolean `false` value, or the empty string. Thus it may or may not be desirable here.

Comment: Seems like something to start however: 
var xxx = new Object_level_2 ( { } );
xxx.setValue ( 'PropA', 345678 ); - fireEvent level_1
xxx.setValue ( 'PropD', 345678 ); - DO NOT fireEvent level_2
???

Comment: these lines: `Object_level_1.superclass.initComponent.call ()` should not have the space after `call`.  not sure if that has anything to do with this not working.  Also, is `this` scoping to the correct object?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I spotted errors in the code:

1. Always declare `var` when creating variables
2. When calling parent's method, use `ClassName.superclass.methodName.call(this, arg1, arg2..)`. It's important to pass the `this` because it will change the scope of the called parent's method to the scope of current object. (You can remove the `this` in my following testing code to see the different outputs).
3. Normally I declare `this.addEvents` in `initComponent` before using the events. Not sure if it's necessary.

Here is my full testing codes with outputs:

```
var Obj1 = Ext.extend(Ext.util.Observable, {
    propA: null,
    propB: null,
    initComponent: function() {
        Obj1.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    },
    setValue: function(name, value) {
        if (name in this) { //Used dtan suggestion
            this[name] = value;
            console.log(this.propA, this.propB, this.propC, this.propD);
        }else{
            console.log(name+" is not in Obj1");
        }
    }
});

var Obj2 = Ext.extend(Obj1, {
    propC: null,
    propD: null,
    initComponent: function() {
        Obj2.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    },
    setValue: function(name, value) {
        Obj2.superclass.setValue.call(this, name, value);
    }
});

var obj1 = new Obj1();
var obj2 = new Obj2();
obj1.setValue('propA', '1a'); //1a null undefined undefined
obj1.setValue('propB', '1b'); //1a 1b undefined undefined
obj2.setValue('propC', '2c'); //null null 2c null
obj2.setValue('propD', '2d'); //null null 2c 2d
obj1.setValue('propA', '1a'); //1a 1b undefined undefined
obj1.setValue('propB', '1b'); //1a 1b undefined undefined
obj1.setValue('propC', '1c'); //propC is not in Obj1
obj1.setValue('propD', '1d'); //propD is not in Obj1
obj2.setValue('propA', '2a'); //2a null 2c 2d
obj2.setValue('propB', '2b'); //2a 2b 2c 2d
obj2.setValue('propC', '2c'); //2a 2b 2c 2d
obj2.setValue('propD', '2d'); //2a 2b 2c 2d
```

Try to read how ExtJS developers write their code in the `src` folders. You will see the correct usages of `Ext.extend`

Comment: var Obj1, var Obj2 will declare varables - reason why I skipped var that I want to declare object ( var obj1 = new Obj1 (Obj1 is var) ???) - reason to separate setValues and whole question is to make sure that seting value will happen in correct method... Try to read a question.

Comment: Sorry, maybe your question is unclear, that's why the answer might not meet your requirement.

Comment: @bensiu This might interest you regarding `var` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript